# How to use the return table data of one procedure in another procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I had a procedure it will return data from a temporary table.The temporary table structure may varies depends on the input parameter of the procedure.This procedure is a general procedure so i cant modify this one.

My requirement is that i want to use the return temporary table data to do some calculation from another procedure.Is it possible to achieve this one????

requirement is some thing like this

```
Create Procedure Proc2 ( @Condition int)  
As  
BEGIN
   execute #temp = Proc1 input1,input2

   select * from #temp where column1 = @Condition 
END
```

This Proc1 is using in some other procedures also so i cant include the condition inside Proc1.

Am using SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Thejus T V

Comment: I do not know what your Proc1 is doing, but: Your question is one of the reasons, why I think that SPs should not be used only to *read* data - which is very common - regrettfully... Maybe you could find a better approach by using (single statement) UDF.

Comment: the issue with UDF is that,return table structure is dynamic.  The proc 1 is a CLR search procedure,it will search for an object out side SQL and return the result in a tabular format.So the output table structure varies depends on the search filters

Comment: Have you thought about an UDF delivering your result "FOR XML" ? This is - at least in my eyes - the best way to deal with unknown structures.

Comment: then there will b performance issue,because in clr first we getting search result as an xml and then from sp its converting into table.So it will be double process.Not only that one,data also will be huge.   Could you please check the reply by madhivanam and its comments by me;

Comment: The given information is not enough to solve your problem. To be honest: On the first sight this seems to need some new thinking... Your CLR method converts an XML in a table and you do not want to convert it back... Why not returning this XML from CLR directly? There is no sense in converting data into a generically structured table. Please give more information about the data given back (how big, how many columns / rows, maybe an exampel...)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a temporary table and use like this

```
Create Procedure Proc2 ( @Condition int) As 
BEGIN

create table #temp(col1 int, col2,....) -- similar to reseultset of proc1
insert into #temp 
execute Proc1 input1,input2
select * from #temp where column1 = @Condition 

END
```

If the column names are unknown you can use OPENROWSET

```
Select 
           *
from 
          OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB','Data Source=Server_name;Trusted_Connection=yes;
          Integrated Security=SSPI','Execute yourdb..proc1')
```

Comment: If the column names and count is unknown, what will do?

Comment: getting this error    ..................................................................................................................... the metadata could not be determined because statement 'select * from #temp' in procedure 'testing' uses a temp table.

Comment: In proc1 am storing the pivoted table data into temp table and returns that temp table data.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the structure being returned by the procedure then you can simply  create a temp table and insert the data into that temp table from the stored procedure result set.

```
Create Table #Temp (Col INT , Col2 INT)

INSERT INTO  #Temp 
Exec Proc1 input1,input2
```

But since you have mentioned you don't know the exact structure of the table begin returned from the stored procedure you can use `OPENQUERY` to manipulate further the result set of a stored procedure something like this....

```
SELECT  *  
FROM  OPENQUERY(YOURSERVERNAME, 'Proc1 input1,input2')
where column1 = @Condition
```